# Where to place json file in Maven JSF Project and how to read and then store that data in the List

Tags: json, maven, jsf-2

Can anybody help me out please?

I am trying to get demo.json data in Maven JSF Application. I want to store that json data into an ArrayList in Backing bean. Later I can display those list data into xhtml datatable format.

I placed demo.json in resources folder but still I am unable to read json data.

Any help would be appreciated!!!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe resources folder is used when you need the file accessible from the outside (a browser). Since you don't seem to need that you could try to put it in web-inf and read it from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resources is the correct location - make sure you are reading it using a technique similar to what is described here: [How to really read text file from classpath in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464291/how-to-really-read-text-file-from-classpath-in-java)